# Скрыть NavigationBar

Tags: android, navigationbar, hide

Здравствуйте.
Задача: скрыть NavigationBar в приложении Android (API 16).
Читал документацию: [Hiding the Navigation Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html) и [Responding to UI Visibility Changes](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html). Из них понял, что скрыть можно, но до первого нажатия, потом сбрасываются флаги. Для исправления этого нужно установить слушателя.
Везде использовал код из документации.
Проблема: Слушатель `setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` вызывается через раз. В debugg он работает исправно: постоянно перерисовывается. При обычной работе приложения - от него нет толка. Почему?

Answer (score 0):

Решение вот [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity). Возможно, вам тоже подойдёт.

```
private int currentApiVersion;

@Override
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    // This work only for android 4.4+
    if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

        // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
        // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
        // show up and won't hide
        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView
            .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                {
                    if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0)
                    {
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus)
    {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Читал этот вопрос. Там указано что это решение для **Android 4.4+**, (т.е. API 19). Моя проблема возникает на 16 api.